# Multi-organization app - switching organization context wording?

Tags: wording, call-to-action

I have a multi-organizational app and I want to give user's the ability to switch the context (which would load different data) between the various organizations that they are a member of.

What's the appropriate wording? Currently I have "Switch Orgs". But that doesn't seem clear that it would be switching the current context. It might be mistaken to mean "switch my organization" instead of "Change my current context to one of my other organizations".

Comment: I think it depends on what happens when they activate the element you're trying to label. Is it a drop-down, modal dialog, or a new page/screen?

Answer (score 2):

You're better off swapping this around and instead using a label which describes which context you're currently in. Think about how social networks cover multiple profiles.

[image: Acting as...]